# How do I create a remote validation code which is reusable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, remote-validation

I need to create the same remote validation on 50 properties.

I have added this remote validation

```
[DropDownSelected("PCP")]
public Guid ProIdentifier { get; set; }
```

and I need to Use this code for 50 different properties but with different names.

Comment: While we recognize that you may need the solution quickly, adding "URGENT ..PLEASE HELP" won't get you your answer any faster.

Comment: Thanx for reading my post 
can please as well help if u do have an idea about how to proceed